# Chaining multiple scopes with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
  scope :target_self, -> { where(target: 'self') }
  scope :target_other, -> { where(target: 'other') }
```

I have the above scopes.

I want to do this : `@example= Example.target_self.target_other`

However, I want it to return all of both target 'self' AND target 'other' (sorry, this is confusing, I want to query to use OR, though i want all the records that have either tag)

Right now, it doesn't return anything, because nothing is labeled with both self and other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write `where(target: ['self', 'other'])`, or add scope like:

```
scope :with_targets, -> (targets) { where(target: targets) }
```

and then call it like `Example.with_tragets([:self, :other])`